# Workflow with deep learning on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have been conducting various projects using deep learning.

Up to now, I have been able to proceed using either google colab, my own machine (Windows) or paperspace.

Now, I need to play with a nvidia library that apparently can only be installed on Linux (or at least I don't have the knowledge to make it Windows compliant).

Therefore, I am looking at using AWS Nvidia AMI to have a machine ready with everything I need.

However, one question that I have never seen discussed is : How do you develop using an Amazon EC2 instance ? Because you only get a command line interface by default. And I have tried getting a remote view of a Linux EC2 instance but it was relatively slow.

So I am wondering : How do people usually go about it ?

When I am on my windows machine, I am using VScode to develop my software : versionning, interactive debugging, ... This is very convenient.

How to do that on AWS ? Or am I missing something ? Maybe people don't debug on AWS and only go on AWS when the software is fully ready ? But in my case I can't do that because I don't have a linux machine so I can't start developing locally and then moving to AWS.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you develop using an Amazon EC2 instance? Because you only get a command line interface by default.

Without knowing what options are available for an AWS Nvidia AMI image specifically, it is possible to do at least some development from a command line environment. That is, command line text editors, versioning software, linters, debuggers, etc. do exist.

> When I am on my Windows machine, I am using VSCode to develop my software: versioning, interactive debugging, ... This is very convenient.

Below are some examples of command line software that be used to perform similar functions. Other solutions may exist as well. In any case, as far as I am aware, AWS AMI images allow you to modify them. So if the particular software you wish to use isn't present in the default image, it's likely it can be added (installed).

**Examples**

*Editing*

`vi` ([Vim](https://www.vim.org/)) is a command line text editor which is often included in Linux. There are other command line editors you could possibly use as well (e.g. [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)), but Vim is robust, relatively ubiquitous and is arguably well suited to programming. It is possible to do things such as [run Python code from Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948491/running-python-code-in-vim) or turn on line numbering (`:set number` in Vim), for example.

*Version Control*

Depending on what version control system you use, there may be a command line interface for it. For instance, Git and Mercurial can both be used entirely from the command line (via `git` and `hg` respectively) assuming they are installed.

*Linting*

[pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) and [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) are probably the widest used Python modules for linting, etc. and both can be used from the command line (e.g. `pylint script.py` and `flake8 script.py`, respectively).

*Debugging*

Python comes with [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), which "defines an interactive source code debugger for Python programs." It can be used directly from the command line (e.g. with `python -m pdb script.py` or `python3 -m pdb myscript.py`) or triggered directly from a script (with `import pdb` and `pdb.set_trace()`). You may want to have a look at this [basic pdb tutorial from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-python-debugger) if you want to see some simple examples of how to use `pdb` directly.

---

*It's probably worth mentioning that all of the items listed above are cross platform i.e. you can practice with them on Windows (as needed). Do note that while Vim is usually `vi` on Linux, it is `vim` on Windows.*

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know most of what you are explaining. The question behind is : Are people actively working in this field doing like this or are they using another way ? Vi/pdb combination is, for me, far less efficient at the moment than VScode. But maybe it's just me